# Nested bundle controller routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Using this approach on this forum [here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2030), i've been able to route sub-domains to bundles.
However am starting to develop my api bundle, and i want to version the api.
I've set up my api bundle like this

- bundles
- bundles/api
- bundles/controllers
- bundles/controllers/v1

I have a `route_file.php` in the root of the bundle folder like in the tutorial above.
This is `route_file.php`

```
/// bundles/api/route_file.php 
// This is included into application/routes.php when default domain used

Route::get('/', 'api::home@index');
Route::controller('api::v1.tasks');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Route Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

Navigating to `api.xyz.com/v1/tasks` i keep getting the `404` page.
Am routing correctly, please point me in right direction

Comment: shouldn't it be `bundles/api/routes.php`?

Comment: @crynobone am using the bundle solution not the nested controller solution http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2030